# Array implode to MySql and then retrieve values and explode back to same array not working if commas already existed in string

Tags: php, arrays

If I implode an array `$arr = ["Hello my, name is Steve", "How are you?"]` to string to insert to MySQL database like so: `$data = implode(',',$arr);`, when I try to retrieve those values and explode it back into array: `$arr2 = explode(',',$data);` it returns : `["Hello my", "name is Steve", "How are you?"]`

How do I get it to ignore the comma thats already in between quotes and explode as:

`["Hello my, name is Steve", "How are you?"]`

Comment: In a case like that, I'd suggest using a character not commonly found in a string, such as `|`

Comment: You should normalize your database design so that you don't store comma separated values.  Alternatively use JSON instead.

Comment: @aynber The string comes from user input in a form, so should I just append a unique character to the end of the input so it can seperate from there?

Comment: I meant use `|` for the imploding/exploding character, so you don't change the user input. But I agree with Nigel, using json would be a lot easier.

Comment: Not every PHP scripts needs to involve implode/explode. Sometimes it's perfectly reasonable to keep JSON as storage format, if preserving structure is beneficial. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use json_encode and json_decode.

Try this out:

```
$arr = ["Hello my, name is Steve", "How are you?"]
$data = json_encode($arr); //Insert $data into mysql 
//Then to retrieve values 
$arr2 = json_decode($data); //returns ["Hello my, name is Steve", "How are you?"]
```